# WiX: Custom action should abort installation

Tags: installation, wix, wix3.5

I have a WiX installer for my application

I made a custom action, calling a function on my dll:

```
<CustomAction Id='CheckPort' BinaryKey='ActionLib' DllEntry='CheckPortAvailability' />
<Binary Id='ActionLib' SourceFile='InstallerActionLibrary.CA.dll' />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action="CheckPort"></Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
</Product>
```

In case the host PC doesn't meet the requirements, the C# custom function inside the DLL displays a popup error message. When the user click "OK" the installer keeps going. What it'd like to do is to abort the installation process. How can I do that in WiX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an attribute Return="check" to the custom action declaration.

In the custom action return failure where needed.

```
return ActionResult.Failure;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have checked `Return="check"` attribute and custom action must be scheduled like: `Execute ="immediate"` to abort the isntallation automatically if custom action returns failure.